# How to call the random list function without chaning it in Python?

Tags: python, dice

I really need help. I defined a function that gives a x number of rolls for n-sided dice. Now I am asked to calculate the frequency of the each side and `freq1 += 1` doesn't seem to work considering there can be many more sides (not just 6) and what I did was;

the first function I defined was `dice(x)`,

```
freq_list = list(range(1,(n+1)))
rollfreq = [0]*n
for w in dice(x):
    rollfreq[w-1] += 1

print zip(freq_list,rollfreq)
```

I get a list such as `[(1,0),(2,4),(3,1)...]` so on, which is expected, yet the problem is the rollfreq valus doesn't match the original randomly generated `dice(x)` list. I assume it is because since it is RNG, it changes the values of the `dice(x)` in the second run as well so that I can not refer to my original randomly generated `dice(x)` function. Is there any solution to this? I mean I tried almost everything, yet it apparently doesn't work!

EDIT:

```
import random

n = raw_input('Number of the sides of the dice: ')
n = int(n)
x = raw_input('Number of the rolls: ')
x = int(x)

def dice():
    rolls = []
    for i in range(x):
        rolls.append(random.randrange(1, (n+1)))
    return rolls
print dice()
freq_list = list(range(1,(n+1)))
rollfreq = [0]*n
for w in dice():
        rollfreq[w-1] += 1

print 'The number of frequency of each side:', zip(freq_list,rollfreq)
```

I have added the code - hope you guys can help me figure it out this, thank you!

Comment: Is the dice function something you wrote yourself? Could you post the code to that as well?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the code to the OP.

Comment: How about assigning the contents of the roll to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called the dice() function twice, once when you printed it, and once when you iterated through it in a for loop. The different results come from there.

```
import random

n = raw_input('Number of the sides of the dice: ')
n = int(n)
x = raw_input('Number of the rolls: ')
x = int(x)

def dice():
    rolls = []
    for i in range(x):
        rolls.append(random.randrange(1, (n+1)))
    return rolls

freq_list = list(range(1,(n+1)))
rollfreq = [0]*n

# Grab the rolls
rolls = dice()
# Print them here
print(rolls)

for w in rolls:
        rollfreq[w-1] += 1

print 'The number of frequency of each side:', zip(freq_list,rollfreq)
```

Comment: nemanjap, thank you very much for the correction, that was exactly what I had need! I tried to call it once but somehow failed to do so :)